# PHP: shortcode doesn't stay within the div tag

Tags: php, html, wordpress

How come when I use this shortcode the `cat_titles` are not inside the `div` ? [check out the example](http://www.aquapumps.org/product-category/brand/be-pumps/)

```
function get_quote($atts) {
    echo    '<div id="le_quote">AquaPumps.Org is your online supplier of '.single_cat_title( '', true ).' Accessories, '.single_cat_title( '', true ).' Hoses and '.single_cat_title( '', true ).' Pumps.  Use our selection to compare '.single_cat_title( '', true ).' models , specs and more. Buy '.single_cat_title( '', true ).' products at the best price possible today.</div>';
}
add_shortcode('random_quote', 'get_quote');
```

Comment: it should be `return` where you have used `echo`. Shortcode should return value, not `echo`. Check the [reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode) please.

Answer (score 3):

try changing `single_cat_title('', true)` to `single_cat_title('', false)`

i think that is for using it in php instead of display

Comment: False is correct. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/single_cat_title but your reasoning is incorrect depending on your definition of 'that'. :P

Comment: $display
    (boolean) (optional) Should the page title be displayed (true) or returned for use in PHP (false).

Answer (score 0):

You should use `return` instead of `echo`.

```
function get_quote($atts) {
    return 'test string';
}
add_shortcode('random_quote', 'get_quote');
```

When you are using `echo`, the shortcode is printed immediately when your function is being processed.

Also, as [Gert suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20943229/1370034), add the `$display` parameter to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

I rather use something like this insted.

```
function get_quote($atts) {
    $title = single_cat_title( '', false);
    echo "<div id='le_quote'>AquaPumps.Org is your online supplier of $title Accessories, $title Hoses and $title Pumps. Use our selection to compare $title models, specs and more. Buy $title products at the best price possible today.</div>";
}

add_shortcode('random_quote', 'get_quote');
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the cat title to a variable then echo that.

```
function get_quote($atts) {
$cat_title = single_cat_title( '', false );
echo    '<div id="le_quote">AquaPumps.Org is your online supplier of '.$cat_title.'     
Accessories, '.$cat_title.' Hoses and '.$single_cat_title.' Pumps.  Use our selection 
to compare '.cat_title( '', true ).' models , specs and more. Buy '.cat_title.' 
products at the best price possible today.</div>';
}
add_shortcode('random_quote', 'get_quote');
```